# How do I get the Compare Validator to work server side?

Tags: asp.net, validation, comparevalidator

I have this compare validator:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cpvBirthDate" Type="Date" ControlToValidate="txtBirthDate" Operator="DataTypeCheck" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date in this format mm-dd-yy">
        <img src="Images/ExclamationMark.gif" alt="Please enter a valid date in this format mm-dd-yy" />
    </asp:CompareValidator>
```

It works on the clientside fine, but if a user has javascript disabled then it accepts 071873 which is not a date. Do I need to write a specific serverside function for this validator to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check `Page.IsValid` in server code before saving entered data

Comment: Thanks, you were exactly right! I don't know how I forgot that!